# How do I disown/detach a process from the Git Bash terminal that come with Git's Windows installer?

Tags: windows, bash, git, mingw, git-bash

I would like to run commands from the terminal (mostly Python servers) and essentially daemonize them.  I am running the MinGW terminal "Git Bash" that comes with the Windows installer for Git.

Things tried that do *not* work:

- nohup -> command not found
- setsid -> command not found
- `$ script.py &` -> does not behave as expected
- `$ script.py & disown` -> does not behave as expected

I would use `bg`, but my end-goal is to close the terminal after my servers are all running and *not* kill the processes.

Answer (score 3):

This is a synthesis from my longer answer to a similar question in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20843432/1851270).

If your app logs to  stdout/stderr, use:

```
cmd //c start cmd //k  "path\\to\\script-dir\\script.py"
```

If it logs to files, via sockets etc. and you do not need  stdout/stderr, use:

```
cmd //c start //D "path\\to\\script-dir" script.py
```

In both cases you get a daemon like process which will survive when you close bash. In the first instance your script is hosted in a visible `cmd.exe` window.

Much more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20843432/1851270).

Answer (score 3):

Simply prefix your command with `start`.

E.g.

```
start TortoiseGitProc /command:showcompare /revision1:master /revision2:HEAD
```

The spawned process inherits the current working directory.

Answer (score 3):

The mixture of `cmd` and `start` *does* work, although both of @antonio 's solutions were "visible" for me. I was trying to find another way, more consistent with MinGW.

## TL;DR

`mintty bash -mc "commands &>/dev/null < /dev/null &"` seems to always work

---

I'm not sure what has all changed since this original post, but using 2.31.1 now, and run git for window's `bash` in a few different ways.

### A subset of what I tried

Here are my results

1. In `mintty` (the "normal" way)

   - Stdin on mintty is a pipe rather than a tty and would require `winpty` in order to get a tty (no idea if this matters)

   I would execute these commands, then close mintty

   | Command | Works? |
   | --- | --- |
   | `git gui` | Nope, the command `git` is called here, and hooked in, so closing the shell kill the git command |
   | `git-gui` | Works, although this is not calling the CLI git anymore, but the windows GUI executable directly, `git-gui`. This is not a general solution |
   | `sleep 60` | Nope |
   | `sleep 60&` | Only if you press Ctrl+D to close, instead of click the X or pressing Alt+F4 |
   | `bash -c "sleep 60&"` | Yes (Still get a warning when you close mintty, but it doesn't kill `sleep`) |
   | `mintty bash -c "sleep 60&"` | Nope |
   | `mintty bash -mc "sleep 60&"` | **Yes**, fully detached |
   | `./foo.bat&` | Nope, `foo.bat` uses stdout, needs to be redirected |
   | `./foo.bat < /dev/null&` | Only if you press Ctrl+D to close, instead of click the X or pressing Alt+F4 |
   | `mintty bash -mc "./foo.bat < /dev/null&"` | **Yes**, fully detached |
   | `winpty bash -mc "./foo.bat&"` | Nope, when stdin is close, the pty dies |
   | `winpty bash -c "./foo.bat&" < /dev/null` | Does not work the first time, works on additional calls |
   | `winpty bash -mc "./foo.bat&" < /dev/null` | Only works like half the time, random |
   | `winpty bash -c "./foo.bat" < /dev/null &` | Only works like half the time, random |
   | `/c/Python39/python foo.py` | Same result as `sleep`/`foo.bat` |
2. In PowerShell

   - Running in powershell does gives stdin a tty

   *Showing different results only*

   | Command | Works? |
   | --- | --- |
   | `sleep 60&` | Nope |
   | `bash -c "sleep 60&"` | Nope |
   | `./foo.bat < /dev/null&` | Nope |
   | `mintty bash -mc "./foo.bat < /dev/null&"` | Nope |
   | `mintty bash -mc "./foo.bat &> /dev/null < /dev/null&"` | **Yes** |
   | `winpty bash -c "./foo.bat&" < /dev/null` | Nope |
   | `winpty bash -c "./foo.bat&" &> /dev/null < /dev/null` | Works half the time, even the first time |
   | `winpty bash -mc "./foo.bat&" < /dev/null` | Nope |
   | `winpty bash -mc "./foo.bat&" &> /dev/null < /dev/null` | Works half the time |
   | `winpty bash -mc "./foo.bat" &> /dev/null < /dev/null &` | Works half the time |

Main difference: First three lines don't work, and stdout/stderr had to be redirected. Which is interesting in the case where a new `mintty` is spawned.

3. In Command Prompt (cmd)

   - Running in cmd does gives stdin a tty
   - Results same as PowerShell
4. In Windows Terminal

   - Running in W Terminal does gives stdin a tty
   - Results same as PowerShell

### What's going on here

- I was attempting to detach stdin/stdout/stderr/and tty
- Some of my earlier tests got `TTY` to say `?` in `ps`, however that did not help
- Based off of the observations with `start`/`cmd`, I was able to get a combo that used `mintty`. I imagine this will handle more cases when it comes to nested quotes, as this keeps the call within the GNU arguments arena, should the need arise.
- It took me a while to find the `winpty`/redirect/bg combo that worked, then I found out that if I try it 10 times in a row, it might work 3 times, it might work 8 times, but usually not 10. It's completely unstable

  - I could now find out why, even using:

    for s in `seq 10`; do winpty bash -c './foo.bat &> foo.$$' < /dev/null; done
  - Not all 10 foo.# files even existed, telling me the bash command didn't even start to get executed.
  - `winpty` executes additional path translation on arguments inconsistent with MinGW's path translations rules, so using `winpty` is generally asking for trouble
- `disown` in bash on MinGW appears to do nothing for or against this endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this will work in bash in Windows, but bash provides a built-in command to "disown" a background process. After you've backgrounded the job with `bg` just run `disown`. By default it will disown the most recently `bg`-ed job, but you can also give it a job number if you have multiple background jobs.

More info here on [Job control built-ins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Job-Control-Builtins).

Comment: Thank you, but like I stated in the original post, disown doesn't seem to be behaving as expected.  Clearly, the problem is the Windows bash terminal; I was just hoping there were alternative ways to do this that I could try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to mintty. Close your bash with 'exit' instead of hitting the [x] button.

In a script you may use 'exit' as last command.